# Unistalling Kiln node

Tags: kiln

I have installed a Kiln node, but now I want to unistall and delete all data connected to node, how to do it?

Where data are stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kiln can be uninstalled using the following command. Note this will remove all the configurations and node data.

```
sudo dpkg --purge kiln
```

It is described well: https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/kiln/blob/develop/docs/distros/ubuntu.md

Comment: Thanks for answering and linking to the docs!